# Simple Java way to input decimal and round to nearest integer

Tags: java

I am using the Java SDK to compile. Need I say, I am a beginner.
Here is the code I tried to use to "Ask user to input decimal and code should output an integer. (round to nearest integer)

```
import java.util.*;

public class readDecimal {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double decimalNumber;
        long intNumber;

        System.out.println(“Please enter a decimal number:“);
        decimalNumber = input.nextDouble();

        intNumber = Math.round(decimalNumber);

        System.out.println(decimalNumber +
                “ rounded to the nearest integer is “ + intNumber);

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I saw the other posts however they seem much to complicated for a beginner. Can you please help?
Thank you,
Diane

Comment: Your code is working properly. Are you experiencing an error?

Comment: It is? Yes I was getting an error. JGrasp said It is? Yes I was getting an error. JGrasp said     
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g readDecimal.java
readDecimal.java:13: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
 System.out.println(ôPlease enter a decimal number: ô);
                    ^
readDecimal.java:13: error: ';' expected
 System.out.println(ôPlease enter a decimal number: ô);
                     ^
readDecimal.java:13: error: ';' expected
 System.out.println(ôPlease enter a decimal number: ô);

Comment: wow I bet you cant even read that, lol.

Comment: I see what the issue is. Try changing your “ characters to ".

Comment: Note: If you ever need to find out what `\uxxxx` means for some 4-digit hex number `xxxx`, go to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_point_planes_and_blocks) which has links to pages for Unicode characters.  In you're case, you'd look at the 2000-2FFF link.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation marks are incorrect; they are unicode for some reason. Replace all the quotations by manual typing them in, in you `System.out.println` statements.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double decimalNumber;
    long intNumber;

    System.out.println("Please enter a decimal number:");
    decimalNumber = input.nextDouble();

    intNumber = Math.round(decimalNumber);

    System.out.println(decimalNumber +
            " rounded to the nearest integer is " + intNumber);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round double numbers using Math.round method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RoundingDecimal {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double num1;
        double num2;

        System.out.print("Please enter a decimal number: ");
        num1 = sc.nextDouble();

        num2 = Math.round(num1);

        System.out.println(" Rounded to the nearest integer is " + num2);    
    }
}
```